# Hibernate: Multiple condition on LEFT JOIN using a criteriaBuiler

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I want make a query where I join 2 tables and i have multiple condition on LEFT JOIN, i know that i can do it using something like:

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Tuple.class);
c.createAlias("table", "t")
 .createAlias("t.metadata", "m", 
 Criteria.LEFT_JOIN, Restrictions.eq("m.field", "CONDITION"));
```

but is posible doing it with a CriteriaBuilder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to do that with a CriteriaBuilder.